# Using react-dates and setState isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-dates

I am trying to implement a cancel feature, where if a user clicks outside the react-dates date picker calendar something happens.

In my calendar component I am setting state for two properties - `startDate` and `endDate` but `endDate` doesn't get set on the state. If I add breakpoints I can see it hits this and tries to set it with a value. If I add the callback function for state being updated, this never gets run, so something weird is happening that I can't resolve.

Why would state not update? There are no errors in the console.

Example code from my calendar component:

```
onDatesChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) => {
    this.setState({ startDate, endDate });
    if (startDate && endDate) {
        this.props.onDatesPicked(startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    }
};

onClose = () => {
    const { startDate, endDate } = this.state;
    if (!startDate || !endDate) {
        this.props.onCancel();
    }
};

render() {
    const { startDate, endDate, focusedInput } = this.state;

    return (
        <div className={css.component}>
            <DateRangePicker
                displayFormat="DD MMM YYYY"
                isOutsideRange={this.isOutsideRange}
                startDate={startDate}
                startDateId={START_DATE}
                startDatePlaceholderText="Start date"
                endDate={endDate}
                endDateId={END_DATE}
                endDatePlaceholderText="End date"
                onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
                focusedInput={focusedInput}
                onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
                firstDayOfWeek={1}
                hideKeyboardShortcutsPanel
                minimumNights={0}
                withPortal
                onClose={this.onClose}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

In the `onClose` function never finds a value for `endDate` even though `setState` has already been called in `onDatesChange` and has passed in a value. There are no issues with `startDate`. If I comment out setting `startDate` then `endDate` does get set fine.

I am so confused...

Comment: Did you check if onDatesChange() method is getting startDate and endDate or not ?

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing: double check the inputs that method is receiving. I wonder if you gave the property names wrong, or if they're actually coming in as two arguments rather than one.

Comment: Yeah endDate definitely has a value, I checked this by adding a breakpoint. Also the if block at the end of the function which only runs if both startDate and endDate are truthy runs happily.